# How to access keydown via function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make sure input on dynamically generated input fields accept only numbers.

This jsfiddle is doing exactly what I want but it isn't allowing for dynamically generated fields: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/.

I've modified it to work with a function but it isn't doing anything.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
Number : <input onkeydown="test(this);" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function test(input) {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  input.keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
}
```

CSS:

```
#errmsg
{
color: red;
}
```

Function version: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/4776/

Comment: where?  Why aren't you posting as answer?

Comment: You can use HTML5 number input types to accept only numbers
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="1000">

Comment: You can still type in letters with that.

Comment: you're fiddle was being weird. also you forgot to wrap `input` in a `$`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/4777/

Comment: @chiliNUT: Awesome! Best response. Please post as answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/4778/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

```
 $('#container', 'input', 'keypress', function() {
     // your code here
 });
```

Comment: it can be body or some wrapping element - its so that you don't apply it to everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input value="" onkeypress="return onlyNumber(event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function onlyNumber(e) {
    e = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```